# Sylius Overriding ShopUser Model

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

I want to override shop_user model of SyliusCoreBundle, I have followed the [instructions](http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/customization/model.html) but there are 2 problems.

1. In doctrine config file when I use "sylius_shop_user" as table name,
   it says that this table already exists.   `The table with name
   'sylius_dev.sylius_shop_user' already exists.`
2. when I want to override shop_user model's class, I get this error:   `Unrecognized option "shop_user" under "sylius_core.resources"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my config for the 1.0.0-alpha.1 :)

```
sylius_user:
    resources:
        shop:
            user:
                classes:
                    model: AppBundle\Entity\ShopUser
                    repository: AppBundle\Entity\Repository\ShopUserRepository
                    form:
                        default: AppBundle\Form\Type\Api\UserType

sylius_resource:
    resources:
        app.shop_user:
            classes:
                model: AppBundle\Entity\ShopUser
                repository: AppBundle\Entity\Repository\ShopUserRepository
                controller: AppBundle\Controller\Api\UserController

sylius_api:
    resources:
        api_user:
            classes:
                model: "%sylius.model.shop_user.class%"

doctrine:
    orm:
        resolve_target_entities:
            AppBundle\Entity\ShopUserInterface: AppBundle\Entity\ShopUser
```

ShopUser.php

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Sylius\Component\Core\Model\ShopUser as BaseShopUser;

class ShopUser extends BaseShopUser implements ShopUserInterface {...}
```

ShopUserInterface.php

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Sylius\Component\Core\Model\ShopUserInterface as BaseShopUserInterface;

interface ShopUserInterface extends BaseShopUserInterface {...}
```

ShopUserRepository.php

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity\Repository;

use Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Doctrine\ORM\UserRepository as BaseUserRepository;

class ShopUserRepository extends BaseUserRepository implements ShopUserRepositoryInterface {...}
```

ShopUserRepositoryInterface.php

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity\Repository;

use Sylius\Component\User\Repository\UserRepositoryInterface;

interface ShopUserRepositoryInterface extends UserRepositoryInterface {...}
```

/src/AppBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/ShopUser.orm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping
                                             http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">

    <entity name="AppBundle\Entity\ShopUser" table="sylius_shop_user" repository-class="AppBundle\Entity\Repository\ShopUserRepository">
        ...
    </entity>

</doctrine-mapping>
```

src/AppBundle/Resources/config/serializer/Entity.ShopUser.yml

```
AppBundle\Entity\ShopUser:
    exclusion_policy: ALL
```